# Changing user controls, using a horizontal animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a list of user controls, that i want to loop through. First i have a "NewsControl" then a "KPI Control", then a "Whats for lunch Control" etc.

I want to be able to animate the transition between each control so that it appears that the first control is pushed to the right, and the next control is pushing in from the left. That is - a horizontal transition. Any ideas on how to do this?

/Cheers

Comment: We had that question before, you just would need to find it, which is almost impossible....

Comment: This should help get you started: http://drwpf.com/blog/category/panels/